# C# WPF Update Status bar text and progress from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar, statusbar

I have a Main window named "wpfMenu" With a status bar which contains a text block and progress bar. The status bar needs to be updated from methods which are running on separate windows launched from the Main window (only one window open at any time).

Preferably I would like to pass the min, max, progress, text values to a class called "statusUpdate" to update the progress but i have no idea where to begin and any examples of updating progress bars I've come across are running on the same window.

Here is my code for the Status bar so far

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon" x:Class="Mx.wpfMenu"
    Title="Mx - Menu" Height="600" Width="1000" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Closed="wpfMenu_Closed">
<Grid>
    <StatusBar x:Name="sbStatus" Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Name="sbMessage" Text="{Binding statusUpdate.Message}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
            <ProgressBar Name="sbProgress" Width="130" Height="18" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="False"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

The code for my class is

```
    public class statusUpdate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _message;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public statusUpdate()
    {

    }

    public statusUpdate (string value)
    {
        this._message = value;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            _message = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(string _message)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_message));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several steps to this, but they're all well documented elsewhere. It might seem like a complex process, but it's something you'll do over and over in WPF.

You're right to store all the settings in a class. However this class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise a PropertyChanged event in every property setter.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class StatusUpdate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string message;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public StatusUpdate()
    {
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return this.message; }
        set
        {
            this.message = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can make it a public property of your code-behind class, and bind your progress bar properties to it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public StatusUpdate Status { get; set; } = new StatusUpdate();

    private void PlayCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    public void PlayCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Status.Message = "Play";
    }

    public void StopCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Status.Message = "Stop";
    }
}
```

Then you can pass a reference to the same class to the child forms, and when they set any of the properties, WPF will catch the event and update the GUI.

Let me know if you can't find an example for any of those steps.

Here's a version of your XAML with the binding and buttons I used for the above example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfProgressBar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfProgressBar"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Play" Executed="PlayCommand_Executed" CanExecute="PlayCommand_CanExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="Stop" Executed="StopCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Play" Command="Play" />
        <Button Content="Stop" Command="Stop" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StatusBar Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status.Message, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
            <ProgressBar Width="130" Height="18" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="False"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

NB, I wouldn't normally do command bindings like this, but didn't want to get into the complications of adding `RelayCommand`

Comment: I updated the post with my statusUpdate class and changed to binding, I think all i need to do now is pass the reference to the child form providing what i have done is correct.

Comment: I just have one slight issue and its probably something simple, despite setting the class and the string to public i cant access the string to assign the value

Comment: What error do you get, and what does your code look like?

Comment: I dont get an error its just when trying to access the statusUpdate class from my child forms using 'statusUpdate.' to access the class the only things which show up are 'Equals' and 'ReferenceEquals', also would my child form have to subscribe to the property changed event

Comment: If those are the only options, you're probably passing the statusUpdate class as an object. Either change the property type, or cast it to the right type. There's no need to subscribe to the event unless your code in one child form needs to be notified when the other one changes it. WPF automatically subscribes to the event to update the GUI.

Comment: okay so my code is as follows `            statusUpdate test = new statusUpdate();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                test.Message = i.ToString();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sbMessage.Text);` the messagebox at the end is to test if the statusbar had been updated but it doesnt look like it is

Comment: I've updated the example, to show how to bind to the same object as you update.

Comment: This works great if the code is placed on the main window where the statusbar is, but if placed on another wpf window the statusbar isnt updated

Comment: Make sure you're passing the same StatusUpdate object, not creating a new one. Only the object that is bound to the GUI can send events to the GUI. If you post all your code in the question, I can try it.

Comment: I got it working by passing the StatusUpdate to the newly opened window, and assigning it to a public StatusUpdate on the new window so it can be accessed by other methods. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: No worries - I went through the same learning process only a few months ago! It actually seems simple once you've set things up in the way that WPF wants to work.